# MongoDB MapReduce weird bug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying this simple MapReduce operation:

```
function map() {

    var gameDay = Math.floor((this.matchCreation - 1427846400000) / 86400000) + 1; // day of april 2015 when the game was played


    this.teams.forEach (function (team){

        **team.bans.forEach(function (ban){** // says bans is undefined

            var value ={
                banned : 1,
                firstBanned: ( ((ban.pickTurn == 1) || (ban.pickTurn == 2))? 1 : 0 )

            }

            emit({championId: ban.championId,
                  day: Number(gameDay)}, value);
            emit({championId: ban.championId,
                  day: "all"}, value);

        });

    });

}

function reduce(key, values) {

    var a = values[0];

    for(var i = 1 ; i<values.length ; i++){

        var b = values[i]; // will merge 'b' into 'a'

        a.banned += (b.banned? b.banned : 0);
        a.firstBanned += (b.firstBanned? b.firstBanned : 0);

        for (var attrname in b){

            if(attrname != "banned" && attrname != "firstBanned")
                a[attrname] = b[attrname];

        }

    }

    return a;

}

matchesCollection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {
    out: { reduce: "mapReduceResults" }

}, function (err, data){

    if(err)
        return callback (err);


    callback (null, "OK");


});
```

It used to work before, but just when I tried to deploy the app after testing for a while, it seems to fail in this line: **team.bans.forEach(function (ban){**, says team.bans is undefined, although every one of the documents has a "teams" array and a "bans" array inside of each object in it, I even double checked it by querying the database and there is no document in which those fields dont exist.

So weird. The reduce function is a bit more complex but it seems to work alright, yet the map one (unlike Reduce, its supposed to be called just once per original document, right?) throws this unexplainable error. Could anyone give me some insight?

Sample input:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5531a63f2a3f135c11ed14a8"
},
"matchId": 1778704162,
"region": "NA",
"platformId": "NA1",
"matchMode": "CLASSIC",
"matchType": "MATCHED_GAME",
"matchCreation": 1427864425511,
"matchDuration": 1431,
"queueType": "URF_5x5",
"mapId": 11,
"season": "SEASON2015",
"matchVersion": "5.6.0.194",
"participants": [
    {
        "teamId": 100,
        "spell1Id": 12,
        "spell2Id": 4,
        "championId": 81,
        "highestAchievedSeasonTier": "SILVER",
        "timeline": [],
        "masteries": [],
        "stats": {
            "winner": false,
            "champLevel": 19,
            "item0": 1037,
            "item1": 3078,
            "item2": 3117,
            "item3": 3035,
            "item4": 3072,
            "item5": 1038,
            "item6": 3340,
            "kills": 7,
            "doubleKills": 1,
            "tripleKills": 0,
            "quadraKills": 0,
            "pentaKills": 0,
            "unrealKills": 0,
            "largestKillingSpree": 3,
            "deaths": 15,
            "assists": 9,
            "totalDamageDealt": 103191,
            "totalDamageDealtToChampions": 22148,
            "totalDamageTaken": 32924,
            "largestCriticalStrike": 669,
            "totalHeal": 2263,
            "minionsKilled": 97,
            "neutralMinionsKilled": 1,
            "neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle": 1,
            "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle": 0,
            "goldEarned": 13923,
            "goldSpent": 13273,
            "combatPlayerScore": 0,
            "objectivePlayerScore": 0,
            "totalPlayerScore": 0,
            "totalScoreRank": 0,
            "magicDamageDealtToChampions": 6082,
            "physicalDamageDealtToChampions": 15803,
            "trueDamageDealtToChampions": 263,
            "visionWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
            "sightWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
            "magicDamageDealt": 45997,
            "physicalDamageDealt": 56651,
            "trueDamageDealt": 543,
            "magicDamageTaken": 25249,
            "physicalDamageTaken": 7490,
            "trueDamageTaken": 184,
            "firstBloodKill": false,
            "firstBloodAssist": false,
            "firstTowerKill": false,
            "firstTowerAssist": false,
            "firstInhibitorKill": false,
            "firstInhibitorAssist": false,
            "inhibitorKills": 0,
            "towerKills": 4,
            "wardsPlaced": 2,
            "wardsKilled": 0,
            "largestMultiKill": 2,
            "killingSprees": 1,
            "totalUnitsHealed": 1,
            "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt": 98
        },
        "participantId": 1,
        "runes": []
    },
   ... (9 more like that)
],
"participantIdentities": [],
"teams": [
    {
        "teamId": 100,
        "winner": false,
        "firstBlood": true,
        "firstTower": false,
        "firstInhibitor": true,
        "firstBaron": false,
        "firstDragon": true,
        "towerKills": 6,
        "inhibitorKills": 2,
        "baronKills": 0,
        "dragonKills": 3,
        "vilemawKills": 0,
        "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
        "bans": [
            {
                "championId": 120,
                "pickTurn": 1
            },
            {
                "championId": 37,
                "pickTurn": 3
            },
            {
                "championId": 13,
                "pickTurn": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "teamId": 200,
        "winner": true,
        "firstBlood": false,
        "firstTower": true,
        "firstInhibitor": false,
        "firstBaron": false,
        "firstDragon": false,
        "towerKills": 11,
        "inhibitorKills": 4,
        "baronKills": 0,
        "dragonKills": 0,
        "vilemawKills": 0,
        "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
        "bans": [
            {
                "championId": 28,
                "pickTurn": 2
            },
            {
                "championId": 38,
                "pickTurn": 4
            },
            {
                "championId": 63,
                "pickTurn": 6
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{ 
_id: { championId: Number, day: Number }
value: { banned: Number, firstBanned: Number }
}
```

After that, its supposed to merge with the results of a previous MapReduce operation, copying all the fields of documents with the same key (in the reduce function), but thats irrelevant now since the error happens before...

Comment: Cheers for that. Currently looking at the MapReduce functions at the same time thinking of maybe using aggregation framework for this?

Comment: @chridam I dont think I can use aggregate for the rates, I'm using it for averaging values but I figured doing it all in a single MapReduce operation would be better, and I dont have time to change that now, i just need to get rid of this bug....

Comment: There is no `teams.bans`. `teams` is an ARRAY - whose objects have such a property. What would work, for example: `teams[0].bans`

Comment: @MörreNoseshine tried that yesterday, doesnt work either :(, notice I'm doing teams.forEach, then, for each team, team.bans.forEach, I'm gonna try that again though

Comment: I'm doing `this.teams[0].bans.forEach` then `this.teams[1].bans.forEach` since in every sample there are only those 2. Edit: failed... `this.teams[0]['bans']` doesnt work either

Comment: @MörreNoseshine update: I've been able to "solve" it with some crappy code that does the same without loops but for some reason doesnt trigger this error... I think that maybe for some matches there are no bans and the api I'm getting this from delivers the field bans as undefined in that cases

Comment: tip: use print or printjson for mapreduce debuging, output will appear in the log file and may be you will get a hint on what is going on

Comment: @nickmilon Thank you, although the project has been delivered already, but I will definitely take a look into that next time as it sounds like it'd make things a lot easier. By the way for anyone browsing this with a similar problem, all I had to do is put `if(team.bans)` before the `forEach` call but I was too tired to realize :p, unrolling the loop and checking every index is defined (as i knew its size) did the trick too